# Redirect apache-tomcat not render via https

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, redirect, liferay

I'm redirecting content from tomcat to apache, the redirecting is working but in some moment fail, the redirecting is working but the content is showed bad, break styles, no images, etc.

In the trace appear some like this  "**WARN [404_jsp:109] /favicon.ico**"

I think maybe the AJP protocol is the problem, some one have had the same problem?.

Part of configuration:

In Apache:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so 
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so 
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so 

Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf

SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/apache2/certs/file.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/apache2/certs/file.key


ProxyPass / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/
```

I have generated a keystore and put it in tomcat.

Tomcat configuration:

```
<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" connectionTimeout="20000" port="8050" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>


<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"  />


<Connector maxThreads="150" port="8009" scheme="https"  clientAuth="false" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"  />
```

I'm doing it for a Liferay Portal and it is running a linux VM.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out what the problem might be based on the information you give, but as nobody answered yet, you might want to check what you did based on [this article](https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/HTTPS+Architecture+with+Liferay) from the Liferay Wiki

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've visited this article before, but didn´t work.